# Service broker cross instances (to different databases)

Tags: sql, service-broker

I am creating a service broker application for a cross instance/server communication. I have been working with Service broker for sometime and I am a little comfortable. my service broker is working for the same instance (different databases messaging)

BUT what I am trying to is send a message from Server 1 to server 2. I have this working using dialog security and necessary service broker objects. Though, what I am trying to do is send a message from [Server 1 database 1] to [server 2 database 1 and database 2 ~ same instance].

I created necessary certificate on [Server 1 database  1] and [Server 2 database 1] and exchanged them  then created all service broker objects. When I send a message from [Server 1 database 1] to [Server 2 database 1] everything works perfect.

BUT,

when I try to also send a message from [server 1 database 1] to [server 2 database 2] (after creating a certificate on the new database and exchange them, the messages will not be send and I see an error in the SQL profile : certificate not found (this error is on server 2 database 2).

Just to give more info, I have the same service name on server 2 database 1 & 2 ...